# Dynamically creating hidden fields in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on Angularjs application, I have a requirement where I have to send hidden variables to a third party application.

Value of these hidden variables should come from database.

I am using following code to dynamically create hidden variables.

```
<input type="hidden" ng-repeat="hdnvar in models.MyModel.templateVariables" name="{{hdnvar.Key}}" id="{{hdnvar.Key}}" value="{{hdnvar.Value}}" />
```

Follwing function is called when user clicks on submit button

```
 $scope.getDetailsForTP = function () {
        $scope.models.MyModel.templateVariables = {};
        $http({
            url: "http://localhost:11149/MyService.svc/TemplateVariable",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                $scope.models.MyModel.templateVariables = response.data;
                $scope.submitForm();
            }
            else {
                alert('Error occurred in fetching template variable data');
            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            //do something
        });
    };

    $scope.submitForm = function () {
        document.getElementById("apirequest").submit();
    };
```

Hidden variables are rendered correctly on a page but when i check fiddler I can't find the hidden variables submitted.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Why are you submitting your form. You can post your data using $http service and pass your modal data (array) in data field of request.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you please provide an example to do that?

Answer (score 1):

you are submitting the form as soon as you updated templateVariables. it takes some time to render html elements.

so you need to submit the form after some delay.

```
$scope.models.MyModel.templateVariables = response.data;
$timeout($scope.submitForm, 1000)  // submit form after 1 second
```

Comment: Adding a delay will solve this. But it might take more than a second to render HTML elements. Is there any way I can submit the form only after rendering of HTML elements?